# Why doesn't my Hello World work in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Can you please tell me where is the bug in this code?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/babel"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        
    <div id="app"></div>

   
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById("#app"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You do NOT need the hash symbol (#) when using document.getElementById. That is only required when using document.querySelector

```js
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work with your modification but in any case I get the error:
Reason: CORS request not HTTP
Reason

Comment: @gianni404 that's completely unrelated.

Comment: Now it actually works by removing # but the reason why it didn't work was due to the fact that I didn't open the index.html file in a web server but I double-clicked on the index.html file so the url file /// ... index .html didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to append `#` in `document.getElementById` so it will become: `ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById("app"));`

Comment: it doesn't work with your modification but in any case I get the error: Reason: CORS request not HTTP Reason